# Странное поведение unlink

Tags: php

Принцип скрипта такой:

Скрипт загружает файл во временную папку и после нажатия на кнопку пользователем перемещает из временной папки в постоянную функцией `rename` и все работает так как нужно. Дело в том, что после того как файл был перенесен в постоянную директорию, то скрипт выполняет ещё кое-какие операции и если что-то пошло не так, то загруженный файл удаляется. В моем случае, я получаю следующую ошибку в попытках удалить файл `Warning: unlink(путь к файлу): Permission denied`

Казалось бы проблема в правах доступа, но нет! С правами все в порядке.

Дело в том, что если написать вручную в каком нибудь `php` файле `unlink(путь к файлу который не удалось удалить в первый раз)` то все удаляется без каких либо ошибок.

Немного покопавший мне удалось понять (но я не уверен) то, что функция `rename` после того как перенесла файл продолжает его блокировать и поэтому удалить файл нельзя. В офф документации нигде не сказано, что это функция блокирует файл и нет способов освободить его.

Какие у вас соображения? Если ли решения для данной задаче?

Comment: привидите код который делает rename?

Comment: Не уверен, что он покажется полезным `rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/tmp/file.zip', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/zips/file.zip')`

Comment: ok `ls -l zips/file.zip` что говорит что бы удостовериться, и где кусок `unlink()` ? код может приведёте хотябы отрывками, а то гадать будем долго, а может переменная не та, а может то а может это в общем.